# Sony Xperia Z3c in-call volume

Tags: rooting, calls, volume, sony-xperia-z3-compact

Is it possible to increase the in-call volume on Sony Xperia Z3 compact. I have rooted my phone and tried various apps, but they only seem to increase the speaker volume and distort it at the same time.

I also tried editing the mixer_paths.xml file, but I do not know which setting corresponds to the earpiece in-call volume level. Or is there another method to increase the volume? The caller is barely audible even in a quiet room and it is frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than mess with xml files, look on XDA for kernels that have faux capability. Typically, you can increase the volume upto 20 dB {3 dB is double)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the suggestion. Although I was able to root following a guide on XDA, I am a bit inexperienced in rooting. I will appreciate it if you can point where to look at. What does faux mean by the way or is there an app requiring super user permissions that can increase volume levels?

Comment: You have rooted already :)  presumably you have a custom recovery also. You need to search for kernel that is meant for your device on XDA and read thorough the thread and decide. That's your decision. Faux capable kernels have the capability to enhance volume as indicated earlier. They may not advertise as such but you need to research if the kernel supports volume enhancement. Search, research and decide